# Plotting lines and the group aesthetic in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question follows on from an earlier [question and its answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349096/group-data-and-plot-multiple-lines-in-r)

First some toy data:

```
df = read.table(text = 
"School      Year    Value 
 A           1998    5
 B           1999    10
 C           2000    15
 A           2000    7
 B           2001    15
 C           2002    20", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

The original question asked how to plot Value-Year lines for each School. The answers more or less correspond to p1 and p2 below. But also consider p3.

```
library(ggplot2)

(p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = Value, colour = School)) +       
   geom_line() + geom_point())

(p2 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(Year), y = Value, colour = School)) +       
  geom_line(aes(group = School)) + geom_point())

(p3 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = factor(Year), y = Value, colour = School)) +       
  geom_line() + geom_point())
```

Both p1 and p2 do the job. The difference between p1 and p2 is that p1 treats `Year` as numeric whereas p2 treats `Year` as a factor.  Also, p2 contains a `group` aesthetic in `geom_line`. But when the `group` aesthetic is dropped as in p3, the lines are not drawn.

The question is: Why is the `group` aesthetic necessary when the x-axis variable is a factor but the `group` aesthetic is not needed when the x-axis variable is numeric?

[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In the words of [Hadley himself](https://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/3f0aba84eeebf74c):

> The important thing [*for a line graph with a factor on the horizontal axis*] is to manually specify the grouping.  By 
>   default ggplot2 uses the combination of all categorical variables in 
>   the plot to group geoms - that doesn't work for this plot because you 
>   get an individual line for each point.  Manually specify group = 1 
>   indicates you want a single line connecting all the points.

You can actually group the points in very different ways [as demonstrated by koshke here](http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/faq-geom_line-doesnt-draw-lines/)

Comment: So when `x` is numeric, assumptions about grouping the observations by the factor aren't made (and can't be made because obviously `x` in not a factor).  I guess what was confusing me in the case of numeric `x` is that it's still possible to get the single line by specifying `group = 1` but multiple lines with no `group` specification.

Comment: Yes, @Sandy Muspratt, in your latter case, numeric `x` provides a natural ordering but no factor to group by, hence other categorical variables come into play. It took me a while to wrap my head around it, now it just is logical. (Thanks for accepting).