# How to plot a sparse (with gaps) line with its segments colored according to some factor in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I have a `data.frame` with time series. There are also `NA`s in it as well as there is a factor that I'd like to use to highlight different segments of a line.

```
flow.mndnr <- function(id, start, end) {
  uri <- sprintf("http://maps1.dnr.state.mn.us/cgi-bin/csg.pl?mode=dump_hydro_data_as_csv&site=%s&startdate=%s&enddate=%s", id, start, end)
  dat <- read.csv(url(uri), colClasses=c(Timestamp="Date"))
  rng <- range(dat$Timestamp)
  d <- data.frame(Timestamp=seq(rng[1], rng[2], by='day'))
  merge(d, dat, all.x=TRUE)
}
dat <- flow.mndnr("28062001", as.Date("2002-04-02"), as.Date("2011-10-05"))
```

I can plot it unconditionally

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Discharge..cfs. ~ Timestamp, dat, type='l', cex=0.5, auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]

But I can't get rid of connecting lines when I try to introduce factor

```
xyplot(Discharge..cfs. ~ Timestamp, dat, type='l',
    groups=dat$Discharge..cfs..Quality, cex=0.5, auto.key=TRUE)
```

[image]

Same with ggplot2

```
dat$quality <- dat$Discharge..cfs..Quality
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Discharge..cfs.)) +
  geom_path(aes(colour=quality)) + theme(legend.position='bottom')
```

[image]

I tried `geom_line` with no success. I read in [ggplot2 mailing archive](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ggplot2/X6J1bxUSSyU/WxMENWQiuGEJ) that `geom_path` is the way to go. But it does not quite work for me.

P.S. Why ggplot2 does not like dots in a name so I had to use another one?

Comment: +1! because you have tried ggplot2 and lattice! reproducible example and clear question.

Comment: Re:dots, in order to work properly, ggplot has to do a fair bit of fancy evaluation of its arguments, so something is likely going wrong there. In general, it would be considered good practice to clean up your column names anyway. A simple `gsub` to remove the dots, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the grouping. You can use the `year` to skip these jumps. Just do:

```
dat$grp <- format(dat$Timestamp, "%Y")
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Discharge..cfs.)) +
    geom_path(aes(colour = quality, group = grp)) + 
    theme(legend.position='bottom')
```

You get:

[image]

**Edit:** To answer the comment in detail: As long as you don't know which variable to group by, you can not group properly. If you have some months missing within the year, of course this code will produce jumps. In that case, I suggest doing something like this:

```
dat$grp <- paste(format(dat$Timestamp, "%Y"), format(dat$Timestamp, "%m"))
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Discharge..cfs.)) +
    geom_path(aes(colour = quality, group = grp)) + 
    theme(legend.position='bottom')
```

You get this:

[image]

Comment: This is not robust. It may work in this case. But it won't help much if there was no data from sensor within a year.

Comment: You'll always have to know which variable to group by. If there is a huge gap within a year, then you'll have to get the month and year separately and paste them together as a `grp`.

Comment: @mlt, probably the alternate (edit) gives you an idea of creating a grouping variable for missing data within year (or other alternate situations).

Comment: I somehow missed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10358388/673826) so it looks like I can get away by just using `groups=1`. Hm... it did not work on the second thought on the aforementioned example :(

Comment: Yes indeed, `group=1`. It (always) skips my mind! Glad you figured it out. I suggest you write it as the answer and mark it as such.

Comment: I still wonder though if it is doable with `lattice`? I had a plan to use `latticeExtra` to attach precipitation on top and I kind of more inclined to c.trellis rather than to grid.arrange