# Plot geom_ribbon with gaps and coloured groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-ribbon

(EDIT: reprex added)

I'm trying to plot both `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon` on data containing `NA` gaps, which is also coloured by some grouping variable `grp` using `fill=grp`. I'd like both line and ribbon to leave gaps for the NAs rather than interpolating.

Example data:

```
> dat <- tibble(datevar=c(1:10), y_var=c(1:10), y_min=c(1:10)*0.8, y_max=c(1:10)*1.2, grp=c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5)))
> dat[3,2:5] <- NA
> dat[8,2:5] <- NA

> dat
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   datevar y_var y_min y_max grp  
     <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1       1     1   0.8   1.2 A    
 2       2     2   1.6   2.4 A    
 3       3    NA  NA    NA   NA   
 4       4     4   3.2   4.8 A    
 5       5     5   4     6   A    
 6       6     6   4.8   7.2 B    
 7       7     7   5.6   8.4 B    
 8       8    NA  NA    NA   NA   
 9       9     9   7.2  10.8 B    
10      10    10   8    12   B
```

For the `geom_line` I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258656/how-to-plot-a-sparse-with-gaps-line-with-its-segments-colored-according-to-som) that works great - just need to add `group=1`, e.g. `geom_line(aes(x=datevar, y=y_var, col=grp, group=1))`.

```
p <- ggplot(dat) + geom_line(aes(x=datevar, y=y_var, col=grp, group=1))
p
```

[image]

So now I get this, where the line is no longer interpolated. But if I add a ribbon, it still is:

```
p + geom_ribbon(aes(x=datevar, ymin=y_min, ymax=y_max, fill=grp), alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

I'm wondering if there's an equivalent solution for the `geom_ribbon`? When I try it with just `group=1` without `fill=grp` it correctly leaves the gaps but doesn't give me colour for the ribbon:

```
p + geom_ribbon(aes(x=datevar, ymin=y_min, ymax=y_max, group=1), alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

When I try to include both, e.g. `geom_ribbon(aes(x=datevar, ymin=y_min, ymax=y_max, fill=grp, group=1), alpha=0.3)`, it gives me the following error:

```
Error in `geom_ribbon()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `draw_group()`:
! Aesthetics can not vary along a ribbon
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Does anyone know a simple solution?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not helpful to post a "short version" and then update later. All the relevant details should be include in the question when it's first posted. It's pretty rare that someone will comeback later to see if missing details have been eventually added.

Comment: Lordy guys it's 4 pm (was 3 pm) the day before Thanksgiving, I just want to get this done   so I can help my family cook and was hoping someone might have an easy solution :( anyway I added a reprex now.

Comment: Your line plot is lying: there is no data for `grp == "A"` at `datevar > 5`, yet the line displays that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to sort by your date variable and then create a column of `consecutive_id` on the `grp` column. You can then color and fill by `grp`, but use the consecutive ID column to group the individual "pieces". Note this fixes the "extra" line that is drawn through the missing data as pointed out by r2evans.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  arrange(datevar) %>%
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(grp)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(datevar, y_var, group = id)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = y_min, ymax = y_max, fill = grp), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(color = grp)) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("turquoise4", "orangered"), 
                    breaks = c("A", "B")) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("turquoise4", "orangered"),
                     breaks = c("A", "B")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

You will get some warnings about ggplot being unable to draw the empty groups, but you can either filter out missing data by adding `filter(complete.cases(.))` to the pipe, or simply ignore the warnings.