# Add a line from different result to boxplot graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image] I have a dataframe (df1) that contains 3 columns (y1, y2, x). I managed to plot a boxplot graph between y1, x and y2, x. I have another dataframe (df2) which contains two columns A, x. I want to plot a line graph (A,x) and add it to the boxplot. Note the variable x in both dataframes is the axis access, however, it has different values. I tried to combine and reshape both dataframes and plot based on the factor(x)... I got 3 boxplots in one graph. I need to plot df2 as line and df1 as boxplot in one graph.

```
df1 <- structure(list(Y1 = c(905L, 941L, 744L, 590L, 533L, 345L, 202L, 
369L, 200L, 80L, 200L, 80L, 50L, 30L, 60L, 20L, 30L, 30L), Y2 = c(774L, 
823L, 687L, 545L, 423L, 375L, 249L, 134L, 45L, 58L, 160L, 60L, 
20L, 40L, 20L, 26L, 19L, 27L), x = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 90L, 90L, 90L
 )), .Names = c("Y1", "Y2", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Y3Line = c(384L, 717L, 914L, 359L, 241L, 265L, 
240L, 174L, 114L, 165L, 184L, 96L, 59L, 60L, 127L, 54L, 31L, 
44L), x = c(36L, 36L, 36L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 99L, 99L, 99L)), .Names = c("A", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

df_l <- melt(df1, id.vars = "x")

ggplot(df_l, aes(x = factor(x), y =value, fill=variable  )) +
geom_boxplot()+
#  here I'trying to add the line graph from df2
geom_line(data = df2, aes(x = x, y=A))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add datasets please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second dataset you have three y values per x value, do you want to draw seperate lines per x value or the mean per x value? Both are shown below. The trick is to first change the x variables in both datasets to factors that contain all the levels of both variables.

```
df1 <-structure(list(Y1 = c(905L, 941L, 744L, 590L, 533L, 345L, 202L, 
369L, 200L, 80L, 200L, 80L, 50L, 30L, 60L, 20L, 30L, 30L), Y2 = c(774L, 
823L, 687L, 545L, 423L, 375L, 249L, 134L, 45L, 58L, 160L, 60L, 
20L, 40L, 20L, 26L, 19L, 27L), x = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 90L, 90L, 90L
)), .Names = c("Y1", "Y2", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Y3Line = c(384L, 717L, 914L, 359L, 241L, 265L, 
240L, 174L, 114L, 165L, 184L, 96L, 59L, 60L, 127L, 54L, 31L, 
44L), x = c(36L, 36L, 36L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 75L, 
75L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 99L, 99L, 99L)), .Names = c("A", 
"x"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df_l <- melt(df1, id.vars = "x")

allLevels <- levels(factor(c(df_l$x,df2$x)))
df_l$x <- factor(df_l$x,levels=(allLevels))
df2$x <- factor(df2$x,levels=(allLevels))
```

Line per x category:

```
ggplot(data=df_l,aes(x = x, y =value))+geom_line(data=df2,aes(x = factor(x), y =A))  + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable ))
```

Connected means of x categories:

```
ggplot(data=df2,aes(x = factor(x), y =A)) + 
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1))  + 
geom_boxplot(data=df_l,aes(x = x, y =value,fill=variable ))
```

Comment: The second dataset contains two columns of new results. However, the second column "x" is the same variable in the first dataset. I managed to graph the boxplot of the first dataset. I need to graph a simple line graph(geom_line()) of the second data and combine it with boxplot graph.

Comment: It gave a vertical line for each data. I need to have a continues line. I know since I have 3 "A" values for each unique x value. But I guess I can still graph it (with the aid of mean function).

Comment: The code is not connecting the lines. I need to get the line is separated from the boxplot. See the update for the required graph.

Comment: You should check my answer better, the last plot does exactly that. The line starts at 36 (in contrast to your latest drawing), but that's due to the second dataset.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm getting this error:" geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?" and it seems due to X variable.??

Comment: It works fine when I run my code so I don't know what the problem is. Try to run my whole code and if it still doesn't work then provide your sessionInfo().

Comment: seems this is a bug in the new version of R!   [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/ECI59jsdOYc/hMJ1Uk4SW-gJ), what is your version?

Comment: sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: Not the version of R but of ggplot2. I'm using ggplot2 0.9.3.1 and R 2.15.2 and don't have the problem. Maybe you should upgrade. When you provide sessionInfo() you should include all the output in your question.

Comment: I thought the bug from R that's why I haven't provided all of the sessionInfo() output. I found that I'm using ggplot2_0.9.3, then I upgraded it to latest. Now it works. Thank you perfect

Comment: @JT85: How does one interpret group=1 in this case? I'm using your answer in part of my code.

Comment: answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2