# ggplot2: Factor for x axis with geom_line doesn't work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a line plot, where `value` is plotted as a function of `expt` with one line per level in `var`:

Here is my data:

```
lines <- "
expt,var,value
1,none.p,0.183065327746799
2,none.p,0.254234138384241
3,none.p,0.376477571234912
1,male.p,-1.58289835719949
2,male.p,-1.98591548366901
3,male.p,-2.02814824729229
1,neutral.p,-2.01490302054226
2,neutral.p,-1.88178562088577
3,neutral.p,-1.68089687641625
1,female.p,-3.27294304613848
2,female.p,-3.07711187982237
3,female.p,-2.89652562347054
1,both.p,-2.40011011312792
2,both.p,-2.24495598015741
3,both.p,-2.78501124223834"
con <- textConnection(lines)
data <- read.csv(con)
close(con)
```

`expt` is a factor:

```
data$expt <- factor(data$expt)
```

Everything works as expected when I use `geom_point`

```
ggplot(data, aes(expt, value, colour=var)) + geom_point()
```

but when I use `geom_line`

```
ggplot(data, aes(expt, value, colour=var)) + geom_line()
```

I get the following error message

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

and an empty plot.  When `expt` is numeric, it works but I prefer to use a factor because that gives me the correct labels on the x-axis.  What's the problem here?  I find it very counter-intuitive that this works with points but not with lines.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To plot a line graph with factors on the x-axis, you need to use `group` in addition to `color`...

```
ggplot(data, aes(expt, value, group=var, color=var)) + geom_line()
```

Gives me this output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I now understand why this is the correct solution but I don't understand why it works when expt is numeric.  Seems like it shouldn't.  Also the error message is probably incorrect.

Comment: @tmalsburg some explanation here: [plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2)