# R ggplot2 (mpg): Group boxplot by year rather than drv

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am working my way through R4DS, and am trying to tweak my solution for [3.8.1 exercise 4](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#exercises-5). I ended up with the following code:

```
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = manufacturer, y = hwy/cty, colour = year)) +
  geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
```

This does not work as intended. But when I replace `colour = year` with `colour = drv`, I get a nice grouped boxplot. Why can’t this be done with `year`?

RStudio 0.99.902; ggplot2 v. 2.1.0.

Comment: try `colour = factor(year)` instead

Comment: Try `str(mpg)` and `as.factor(year)` to find an answer by yourself ;)

Comment: Cheers, guys; changing it to factor was the solution, though I don't know what it does (_v. inf._).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work when you write it into geom_boxplot.

```
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = manufacturer, y = hwy/cty)) +
geom_boxplot(aes(colour=factor(year))) + coord_flip()
```

Comment: As they noted above, the grouping variable needs to be a factor.

Comment: Your solution works just as I intended. Could you, in your answer include an explanation on what factor does to the variable?

Comment: This is a good explanation on how grouping works in ggplot ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2