# ggplot2 geom_line() not ploting lines

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw a simple line plot using ggplot geom_line()

my code is very simple:

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(data()$Date))
colnames(df) <- c('Date','value')

volPlot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date,y = value))
volPlot <- volPlot + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_line(size = 3)

return(volPlot)
```

df looks like this:

```
         Date value
1  2016-06-01   379
2  2016-06-02   262
3  2016-06-03   264
4  2016-06-04   167
5  2016-06-06   410
```

The plot shows the points but no line in between them which is what I want

Note: the console returns the following message:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
>   adjust the group aesthetic?

So I suppose the problem comes from my data structure but I don't know how to prevent this, any help would be nice.

EDIT: Solution was found, you need to add group = 1 in the aes:

```
volPlot <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date,y = value, group = 1))
```

Comment: Date is interpreted as a factor - you probably want to do `lubridate:parse_ymt()`first.

Comment: It should be `table(data$Date)` in your first line

Comment: ..AND, the reason of the error: You need a group aesthetic. `group = 1` should suffice in this case

Comment: ...And add `group=value` inside your `aes()`.  And `print(volPlot)` rather than `return`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar the `data()` and `return()` may indicate this is part of a Shiny app, where both would be ok

Comment: It is part of a Shiny App so data() and return() are normal here, 
@GGamba your solution worked perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With purely numerical Dates as in

```
data<-cbind(Date=1:5,Value=c(379,262,264,167,410))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date,y = value))+geom_point(size = 3) + geom_line(size = 3)
```

it works just as expected - lines show up. As laid out by @GGamba, with your factorial presentation of dates, you need to help it a bit as in

```
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(Date=LETTERS[1:5],value=c(379,262,264,167,410)))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Date,y = value))+geom_point(size = 3) + geom_line(aes(group=1),size=3)
```

I just found more on [Plotting lines and the group aesthetic in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2) .