# ggplot sub-plots with categorical and numeric in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a the following table and I need to plot this to show (week in x-axis and percent in y-axis). MY following code plots nothing but gives me a message. Can someone help me to fix this?

Any help is appreciated.

```
dfx1:

Year  State  Cty        Week   ac_sum    percent
1998  KS     Coffey     10-1   79        6.4
1998  KS     Coffey     10-3   764       62
1998  KS     Coffey     10-4   951       77.2
1998  KS     Coffey     10-5   1015      82.4
1998  KS     Coffey     11-2   1231      100
1998  KS     Crawford   10-3   79        6.1
1998  KS     Crawford   10-4   764       15.8
1998  KS     Crawford   10-5   951       84.1
1998  KS     Crawford   11-2   1015      100
.
.
.
.


gg <- ggplot(dfx1, aes(Week,percent, col=Year))
gg <- gg + geom_line()
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Cty, 2, scales = "fixed")
gg <- gg + xlim(c(min(dfx1$Week), max(dfx1$Week)))
plot(gg)

geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
adjust the group aesthetic?
```

Comment: Just add `group=1` to you r code and It will work. `ggplot(dfx1, aes(Week,percent, col=Year, group=1))`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
dfx1 <- read.table(text="Year  State  Cty        Week   ac_sum    percent
1998  KS     Coffey     10-1   79        6.4
1998  KS     Coffey     10-3   764       62
1998  KS     Coffey     10-4   951       77.2
1998  KS     Coffey     10-5   1015      82.4
1998  KS     Coffey     11-2   1231      100
1998  KS     Crawford   10-3   79        6.1
1998  KS     Crawford   10-4   764       15.8
1998  KS     Crawford   10-5   951       84.1
1998  KS     Crawford   11-2   1015      100", header=T)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfx1, aes(Week,percent, col=Year)) + 
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~Cty, 2, scales = "fixed")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(dfx1, aes(Week,percent, col=Year, group=1)) + 
    geom_point() + geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~Cty, 2, scales = "fixed")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. thats right. but I need a line not dots for all the years.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at other answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2) to see that you're missing `group = Year` in your plot. Adding it in will give you what you are looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)

dfx1$Week <- factor(dfx1$Week, ordered = T)

ggplot(dfx1, aes(Week, percent, col = Year, group = Year)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Cty, 2, scales = 'fixed')
```

[image]

With your last line it looks like you're wanting to only show the `Week`s that actually have data. You can do that with `scales = 'free'`, like so:

```
ggplot(dfx1, aes(Week, percent, col = Year, group = Year)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Cty, 2, scales = 'free')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried yours above but in my huge dataset I have "Week" column data starting from 6-1. I want the X-axis to be fixed. So in the plots x-axis labels starts from 10-1 and after 10-5 it shows 6-1 and then 9-1, 9-2, etc..How can I format the X-axis to start from 6-1. Right now my plot does not make any sense because of the X-axis labels.

Comment: Basically I need to get the min and max of X-axis labels here.

Comment: Looks tricky. I'm not sure you can specify differing xlims across your different facets beyond just `scales = 'free'`

Comment: OK. Then, is there as way I can order the 'Week" column from lowest ti highest before it plots. Order from for example, from 9-1, 9-2, 9-3, 9-4, etc. for each "Cty"

Comment: even if I use scales = "free" it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I apologize, I added in the line where I made `Week` an ordered factor. I mistakenly omitted it before. Then when I used `scales = 'free'` it will at least leave them in the right order.

Comment: Thanks. I tried ordering as factors of the "Weeks" but still it DID NOT correct the issue.