# Set only one aesthetic to show up in ggplo2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that uses both the line type and color aesthetic.  The legend shows both aesthetics but I would only like one aesthetic (either color or line type) in the legend itself.

This also applies to another data set in which I want only one out of four lines larger than the rest which I do with an `ifelse` statement in the geom_line aesthetic, but the actual `ifelse` statement shows up in the legend.

I've taken an example from the `mtcars` data set where I want only color to show up.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars <- as.tibble(mtcars)

mtcars$gear <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%
  arrange(gear) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = qsec, group = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=disp, group = cyl, color = cyl)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=disp, group = cyl, color = cyl, linetype = cyl)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + 
  labs(title = "MTCARS Example", colour="Cylinder",x= "x",y="Disp") 
print(mtcars1)
```

Is it possible to manipulate the legend to only show one aesthetic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
mtcars1 + guides(color = "none")
mtcars1 + guides(linetype = "none")
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: use same legend name: `labs(colour = "Cylinder", linetype = "Cylinder)`.

```
# Simplified version of the same plot
library(ggplot2)
# 1. All aes specified in main ggplot2 function
# 2. In aes x always goes first, y always goes second,
#    you don't need to write x = ..., y = ...
ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, disp, color = cyl, linetype = cyl)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + 
    # For "tidier" code use same order as in aes 
    # (except for main title, or subtitle)
    labs(title = "MTCARS Example", 
         x = "x",
         y = "Disp", 
         color = "Cylinder", 
         linetype = "Cylinder")
```

If you want to use combined legends you have to use same variables for `aes` (you're already doing that). By default legend name would be `cyl`. But when you change name for a single aesthetics (`color = "Cylinder"`) `ggplot2` thinks that you're using two different variables. Thus you have to rename both aesthetics for a plot like this:

[image]

PS.: I simplified your `ggplot2` function. Don't rewrite `y=disp, color = cyl` multiple times, set them in main `ggplot2` function. Also, you don't need `group` (have know idea what you tried to do there).

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas.  I read some where I needed it.  (I'm newish to R)  Why would someone use `group`?

Comment: @Jordan Take a  look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2) (tl;dr use it for factors). Also, you **don't** need `print` to show plot, just type `mtcars1`.