# ggplot plotting vertical lines only?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When entering the following code, I get a weird ggplot where it plots vertical lines.

```
ggplot(data = otherdata, aes(x = subject, y = pct_.below)) + geom_point(aes(colour = subgroup))
```

[image: geom_line]

[image: geom_point]

When doing `geom_point` rather than `geom_line`, I get the other graph. I have no idea why this happens. There are more points than there are subgroups but that's not the solution to the issue. What do I do to fix this ggplot?

```
# dummy data
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, 9), val=sample(1:100, 45), 
               variable=rep(paste0("category", 1:9), each=5))
# plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=val)) + geom_line(aes(colour=variable))
```

That code that I just posted works but I have no idea what the difference is between the two codes.

First 20 rows of the data:

```
structure(list(subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Algebra II", 
"Biology I", "Chemistry", "English I", "English II", "English III", 
"Geometry", "Int Math I", "Int Math II", "Int Math III", "US History"
), class = "factor"), pct_.below = c(0, 12.5, 12.4, 12.5, 0, 
0, 12.5, 8.4, 11.1, 12.8, 11.9, 0, 11.5, 9, 100, 66.7, 100, 100, 
100, 50), subgroup = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("All Students", 
"Asian", "Black or African Amer", "Black/Hispanic/Native Amer", 
"ED", "English Learner T 1-2", "English Learner T 1-4", "English Learners", 
"English Learners with T 1-2", "English Learners with T 1-4", 
"Hispanic", "Non-Black/Hispanic/Native Amer", "Non-ED", "Non-English Learners/T 1-2", 
"Non-English Learners/T 1-4", "Non-Students with Disabilities", 
"Students with Disabilities", "Super Subgroup", "White"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: 1) This can happen if your `x = subject` is categorical, a vector of class `"factor"`. 2) In order to post the original data, post the output of `dput(otherdata[1:20, c('subject', 'pct_.below', 'subgroup')])` **in the question**.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data that actually produces the problematic chart. Can't help you figure out the problem if we can't reproduce it.

Comment: added the output as Rui stated to do so. It's not very pretty but hope you guys can do something with it.

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = otherdata, aes(x = subject, y = pct_.below, group = subgroup)) + geom_line(aes(colour = subgroup))`

Comment: I think that did it, thanks Jon Spring!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting lines and the group aesthetic in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2)