# geom_line don't show line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the dual facet plot of one bar graph and line graph.

But I **can't get the line** in my line graph **without any error code**.

I googled it before, and some people said they could add the aes(group=1) when drawing the line graph. But with the aes(group=1), it can't separate the data into groups as I ordered.

I used this code on other datasets, and they work well. I don't know why they don't work on this data set.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
        
zone <- structure(list(location = c("rm", "jj", "jsy", "hyh"), cropland_2018 = 
    c(0.92330383480826, 
    0.887755102040816, 0.813559322033898, 0.771653543307087), urban_2018 = c(0.0176991150442478, 
    0.0283446712018141, 0, 0.00393700787401575), nature_2018 = c(0.0589970501474926, 
    0.0839002267573696, 0.186440677966102, 0.224409448818898), cropland_change_rate2018_2001 = 
   c(0, 0, 0, -0.069620253164557), urban_change_rate2018_2001 = c(0.0526315789473684, 
    -0.281553398058252, 0, 0), nature_change_rate2018_2001 = c(-0.00294117647058824, 
    -0.00898876404494382, -0.0833333333333333, 0.0363636363636364
    )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
        
        
 z=zone %>% pivot_longer(cols=cropland_2018:nature_2018, names_to = "landcover", values_to = 
    "area_percent") 
 df=z %>% pivot_longer(cols=cropland_change_rate2018_2001:nature_change_rate2018_2001, names_to = "change", values_to = "rate_20y")
 dfF <- rbind(
          data.frame(
          location=df$location, 
          num=df$rate_20y,
          group=df$change, 
          what="rate_20y"),
          data.frame(location=df$location, 
                      num=df$area_percent, group=df$landcover,what="area_percent")
        )
 secondFacet <- FALSE # see below
 ggplot(data = dfF, mapping = aes(x = location, y = num,fill=group,color=group)) +
 facet_grid(what~., scale = "free") +
 geom_line(data=dfF[dfF$what=="rate_20y",],size = 2) +
 scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#E69F00", 
     "#56B4E9","#56B4E9"))+
 geom_bar(data=dfF[dfF$what=="area_percent",],position="dodge", stat="identity") +
 scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#56B4E9"))+
 theme_bw()+
 scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, labels = function(b) {
            if(!secondFacet) {
 secondFacet <<- TRUE # this is a little cray (and relies on dtF seq = facet seq; works though)
              return(paste0(round(b * 100, 0), "%"))
            }else{
              return(b)
            }
          })
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Add `aes(group=group)` to your `geom_line()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting lines and the group aesthetic in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the question and I see @MrFlick provided the answer, but as a comment. Adding below the answer, so that the question can be closed:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

zone <- structure(list(location = c("rm", "jj", "jsy", "hyh"), cropland_2018 = 
                         c(0.92330383480826, 
                           0.887755102040816, 0.813559322033898, 0.771653543307087), urban_2018 = c(0.0176991150442478, 
                                                                                                    0.0283446712018141, 0, 0.00393700787401575), nature_2018 = c(0.0589970501474926, 
                                                                                                                                                                 0.0839002267573696, 0.186440677966102, 0.224409448818898), cropland_change_rate2018_2001 = 
                         c(0, 0, 0, -0.069620253164557), urban_change_rate2018_2001 = c(0.0526315789473684, 
                                                                                        -0.281553398058252, 0, 0), nature_change_rate2018_2001 = c(-0.00294117647058824, 
                                                                                                                                                   -0.00898876404494382, -0.0833333333333333, 0.0363636363636364
                                                                                        )), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                        ))


z=zone %>% pivot_longer(cols=cropland_2018:nature_2018, names_to = "landcover", values_to = 
                          "area_percent") 
df=z %>% pivot_longer(cols=cropland_change_rate2018_2001:nature_change_rate2018_2001, names_to = "change", values_to = "rate_20y")
dfF <- rbind(
  data.frame(
    location=df$location, 
    num=df$rate_20y,
    group=df$change, 
    what="rate_20y"),
  data.frame(location=df$location, 
             num=df$area_percent, group=df$landcover,what="area_percent")
)
secondFacet <- FALSE # see below
ggplot(data = dfF, mapping = aes(x = location, y = num,fill=group,color=group)) +
  facet_grid(what~., scale = "free") +
  geom_line(aes(group=group), data=dfF[dfF$what=="rate_20y",],size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#E69F00", 
                              "#56B4E9","#56B4E9"))+
  geom_bar(data=dfF[dfF$what=="area_percent",],position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#999999", "#E69F00", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#56B4E9"))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(name = NULL, labels = function(b) {
    if(!secondFacet) {
      secondFacet <<- TRUE # this is a little cray (and relies on dtF seq = facet seq; works though)
      return(paste0(round(b * 100, 0), "%"))
    }else{
      return(b)
    }
      
})
```