# How to Combine bar and line chart in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df:

```
 Sample_ID = c("LSL Guideline", "USL Guideline", "P1014B", "P1014F", "P1036A", "P1036B", P1036C","P1036D" ,"P1036E, "P1036F")
    CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA) = c(0, 3106, 2677, 1021, 870, 6831, 1324, 4175, 1370,  875)
    CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA) = c(0.000, 0.049, 0.101, 1.000, 1.000, 0.000, 1.000, 0.036, 1.000, 1.000)
    df <- data.frame(Sample_ID, CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA), CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA) )

> df
       Sample_ID CONTAMINATION_SCORE..NA. CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE..NA.
1  LSL Guideline                        0                      0.000
2  USL Guideline                     3106                      0.049
3         P1014B                     2677                      0.101
4         P1014F                     1021                      1.000
5         P1036A                      870                      1.000
6         P1036B                     6831                      0.000
7         P1036C                     1324                      1.000
8         P1036D                     4175                      0.036
9         P1036E                     1370                      1.000
10        P1036F                      875                      1.000
```

I am trying to follow the guide here:

[Combine bar and line chart in ggplot2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combine-bar-and-line-chart-in-ggplot2-in-r/)

I want to plot all but the first 2 rows of df and have the following code.
It nearly works as the guide says but the second axis isn't working?? E.g. I want to see the `CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)` column as the line on the second axis as the guide shows

```
  ggplot(df[-c(1,2),])  + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=Sample_ID, y=`CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)`),stat="identity", fill=rainbow(n=length(df$Sample_ID[-c(1:2)])))+
    geom_line(aes(x=Sample_ID, y=`CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)`),stat="identity",color="red")+
    labs(title= " QC",
         x="Sample ID",y=" Score") +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*0.01,name="Percentage"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code. First you have to add the `group` aes to the `geom_line` as your x variable is a categorical (whereas in the blog post it's a numeric). Second, when dealing with a secondary axis you (!!) have to rescale your data, i.e. in the blog post the values are multiplied by 100 (besides the inverse transformation in `sec.axis`). However, the scaling always depends on the data to be plotted. IMHO for your data a scaling by 10000 seems more appropriate which will you a secondary axis running from 0 to 100 percent.

```r
Sample_ID <- c("LSL Guideline", "USL Guideline", "P1014B", "P1014F", "P1036A", "P1036B", "P1036C", "P1036D", "P1036E", "P1036F")
`CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)` <- c(0, 3106, 2677, 1021, 870, 6831, 1324, 4175, 1370, 875)
`CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)` <- c(0.000, 0.049, 0.101, 1.000, 1.000, 0.000, 1.000, 0.036, 1.000, 1.000)
df <- data.frame(Sample_ID, `CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)`, `CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)`, check.names = FALSE)

library(ggplot2)

df <- df[-c(1, 2), ]
pal <- rainbow(n = length(unique(df$Sample_ID)))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x = Sample_ID, y = `CONTAMINATION_SCORE (NA)`, fill = Sample_ID)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Sample_ID, y = `CONTAMINATION_P_VALUE (NA)` * 10000, group = 1),
    color = "red"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal, guide = "none") +
  labs(title = " QC", x = "Sample ID", y = " Score") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 10000, name = "Percentage", labels = scales::percent))
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, I see, thank you @stefan. Could you explain a little more what the group = 1 is? I don't quite understand...is it stipulating that each value in that column is a part on the x-axis? Also, my values for the line graph is actually a p-value not a percentage  - do you have any ideas how I can scale the second y-axis better (e.g. to display better the 0.049 AND the 1.000)

Comment: If your x variable is a categorical variable ggplot2 will by default group (or split) the data by this variable (actually all categorical variables). In case of a geom_line this means that only obs belonging to a group are connected. `group=1` overrides the grouping and tells ggplot to treat all obs as belonging to one group which we call 1, i.e. `group="foo"` will also work. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357768/plotting-lines-and-the-group-aesthetic-in-ggplot2 and https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html.