# Lines not connecting the right way with plot function in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm working on plotting data with the Indometh data set.

There's an extra line connecting the first and last data points of each subject. How do I remove this line? Is it an issue with how my data is sorted?

My code:

```
plot(Indometh$time, Indometh$conc, type = "l")
```

Edited:

Solution:

```
plot(Indometh$time[Indometh$Subject == "1"], Indometh$conc[Indometh$Subject == "1"]) 

## Line for subject 2
lines(Indometh$time[Indometh$Subject == "2"], Indometh$conc[Indometh$Subject == "2"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Indometh, aes(x = time, y = conc)) + 
        geom_line()
```

[image]

Or for each 'Subject

```
ggplot(Indometh, aes(x = time, y = conc)) +
        geom_line(aes(color = Subject))
```

[image]

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `matplot`

```
matplot(xtabs(conc ~ time + Subject, Indometh), type = 'l', ylab = 'conc')
```

#### Update

To set a custom color

```
colr_set <- rainbow(6)[as.integer(levels(Indometh$Subject))]
matplot(xtabs(conc ~ time + Subject, Indometh), type = 'l',
   ylab = 'conc', col =colr_set)
legend("left", legend = levels(Indometh$Subject), 
          lty = c(1, 1), lwd = c(2.5, 2.5), col = colr_set)
```

Comment: @user12310746 In the first solution, you can create a column of colors by mapping the values to that 'Subject' and then use `color = ` that column

Comment: @user12310746 for me it is showing different colors `ggplot(Indometh, aes(x = time, y = conc)) 
+         geom_line(aes(color = colors))`

Comment: @user12310746 if it is for the matplot, just do `matplot(xtabs(conc ~ time + Subject, Indometh), type = 'l', ylab = 'conc', col = rainbow(6))`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple groups (Subject number), and they are all being plotted as one line. So once it gets to the end time for one subject, it connects that point to the first time for the next subject.

See [Group data and plot multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349096/group-data-and-plot-multiple-lines)  for how to fix this.