# Multiple Line, Line Graph Coding with R (or Excel?)

Tags: r, excel, graph

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to code a line graph with two lines in R, as I am incredibly new, and a lot of the material I have viewed is making me rather confused. I'm trying to make one looking at infant birthweight between smokers and non smokers. I have an CSV file with ~189 people in. I hope to have age on the X axis, the birthweight on the Y, and two lines on the graph - one for smokers, and one for non smokers.

I have the data saved as data, and age is data$AGE, birthweight is data$BWT, and smoking status is data$SMOKE. Also, in the CSV file '0' signifies a non smoker, and '1' signifies a smoker.

If there is a way to make one like I described in Excel that would be equally great.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If you are using `ggplot2` then `ggplot(data, aes(AGE, BWT, colour = SMOKE)) + geom_line()`

Comment: In base R, try `plot(data$AGE[data$SMOKE == 0,], data$BWT[data$SMOKE == 0,])` followed by `lines(data$AGE[data$SMOKE == 1,], data$BWT[data$SMOKE == 1,], col = "red")`

Comment: Seems like a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349096/group-data-and-plot-multiple-lines).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.